# How can I get the width and height of a text string with CAM::PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf

I use the following to read a PDF file and get text strings of a page:

```
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($pdf_file);
my $pagetree = $pdf->getPageContentTree($page_no);

# Get all text strings of the page
# MyRenderer is a separate package which implements getTextBlocks and
# renderText methods

my @text = $pagetree->traverse('MyRenderer')->getTextBlocks;
```

Now, `@text` has all the text strings and start x,y of each text string.

How can I get the width (and possibly the height) of each string?

MyRenderer package is as follows:

```
package MyRenderer;
use base 'CAM::PDF::GS';
sub new {
    my ($pkg, @args) = @_;
    my $self = $pkg->SUPER::new(@args);
    $self->{refs}->{text} = [];
    return $self;
}

sub getTextBlocks {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return @{$self->{refs}->{text}};
}

sub renderText {
    my ($self, $string, $width) = @_;
    my ($x, $y) = $self->textToDevice(0,0);
    push @{$self->{refs}->{text}}, {
                                    str => $string,
                                    left => $x,
                                    bottom => $y,
                                    right =>$x + $width,
                                   };
    return;
}
```

**Update 1:**
There's a function **getStringWidth($fontmetrics, $string)**
 in CAM::PDF. Altough there's a parameter $fontmetrics in that function, irespective of what I pass to that parameter, the function returns the same value for a given string.

Also, I am not sure of the unit of measure the returned value uses.

**Update 2:**
I changed the renderText function to following:

```
sub renderText {
    my ($self, $string, $width) = @_;
    my ($x, $y) = $self->textToDevice(0,0);
    push @{$self->{refs}->{text}}, {
                                str => $string,
                                left => $x,
                                bottom => $y,
                                right =>$x + ($width * $self->{Tfs}),
                                font => $self->{Tf},
                                font_size => $self->{Tfs},
                               };
    return;
}
```

Note that in addition to getting font and font_size, I multiplied $width with font size to get the real width of the string.

Now, only thing missing is the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getStringWidth() depends heavily on the font metrics you provide.  If it can't find the character widths in that data structure, then it falls back to the following code:

```
   if ($width == 0)
   {
      # HACK!!!                                                                   
      #warn "Using klugy width!\n";                                               
      $width = 0.2 * length $string;
   }
```

which may be what you're seeing.  When I wrote that, I thought it was better than returning 0.  If your font metrics seem good and you think there's a bug in CAM::PDF, feel free to [post more details](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=CAM-PDF) and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Chris.
Check my update 2 in OP.
Hope what I did was right to get the width.