# How to get the X,Y coordinates of a point in a PDF

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF template file. It has a bunch of fields I need to write to using PHP. How can I easily determine the xy coordinates of a field in the file? Right now I am using xy locations but trial and error is very time consuming. Is there a better way to do this? Or even an easy way to get the xy coordinates of a point in a pdf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form-filling part of your question seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873/filling-pdf-forms-with-php/112712#112712).  As for coords, I can't help with PHP but I have a good Perl solution for this.  Here are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620470/how-can-i-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-text-string-with-campdf) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196788/how-do-i-get-character-offset-information-from-a-pdf-document/203553#203553) about computing X,Y coords of text.  CAM::PDF has a [fillformfields.pl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/bin/fillpdffields.pl) utility that can help.

Comment: Any php version available?

Comment: @RNKushwaha - not that I can help with, no. I'm not really a PHP user these days.

Answer (score 19):

In order of my preference:

**Mac**:
   *Skim* - Select a Text Box.  Look on the bottom right for X,Y, plus the box height & width.

*Preview* (included in OSX), Select a Text Box:
           Tools -> Show Inspector -> pick 4th tab that has a little ruler icon.
           This gives coordinates, but with an upper-left origin (web standard origin,
           but not the pdf convention)

**Linux and Unix**:  don't know, but try...
  *GSView* 
  *xpdf* 
  *evince*
  *gnome-gv*

**Windows**:
  *GSView* is now my favorite: fast, convenient alway-on coordinate display, free

*Foxit Reader*,  free for reading coordinates (see 'Properties' box),
                 $100 if you want to save file revisions.

*Foxit Phantom* ($130) does not display coordinates.

*PDF-Xchange* will also do it for free, but the Y origin is upper-left, not lower-left,
             so you have to subtract every Y from your page height.
             And the coordinates have to be interpreted by reading an edge scale,
             which is hard to do accurately.

*Adobe Acrobat* - A sales and a tech support ticket I filed say that the $700 reader
             will do it.  I haven't checked.

Comment: GSView (6.0 Beta but hasn't been update since 2015...) on windows had no option to see the coordinates

Comment: The Mac solution does not seem to work anymore (Preview Version 10.1)

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work on preview. The "selection" top/left remains empty at all time.

Comment: On the other hand, now it says "crop" and selecting the crop tool allow you to draw crop boxes and get the crop-box coordinates. Which seems even better than using text box anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's better late than never to answer this:

Foxit PDF Editor (now incorporated into Foxit PhantomPDF Standard or Business) will display the coordinates of any object in a PDF file.  The only problem you have to go through every object individually - manually click on the object and read off the coordinates.  I haven't found an automatic way to extract the coordinates and pipe them into a PHP script.