# How to find coordinate of desired text in PDF file using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have been looking for the way to find the coordinate of string in PDF using PHP I searched in GOOGLE and also looked into many questions in SO, but didnt find something relevant, can someone help me in finding me the solution...

Comment: first GOOGLE result: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

Comment: @fabrik I Have editted the question could u pls go thru it again plsss.

Comment: Do you like to create some highlight script like Google Books?

Comment: @fabrik No, I Just want to find the coordinates of the desired text in file and place an image below it.

Comment: Look here, not really PHP but hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668031/how-to-get-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-point-in-a-pdf/668564#668564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php),, it descripes what is needed to do and then shows you some code and a usage example. It gets the text out of a pdf file. Then you can use php [strpos function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to search for a string in it.

Maybe [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196788/how-do-i-get-character-offset-information-from-a-pdf-document/203553#203553) can help you. It is in perl but does the job I think. Maybe you can rewrite the code for php.

- Please mark as answer if this helped.

Comment: You're the legend! Where do you find that link?

Comment: certainly ur answer is helpful, but I have changed my question a bit pls have a look

Comment: oh snap,, @fabrik my bad,, I now saw your comment. But it is indeed the first google result. :p

Comment: link in the answer is dead.