# How to Print a Page to PDF Only with X Y Coordinates

Tags: java, javascript, html, pdf, applet

I got a peculiar problem. I am business analyst working on a dash-boarding product based on java applet. I don't have access to any elements in the java applet it's like a black box.

I am looking to print a section of page without using html elements (since I don't have access to code). Ideal case would be using something like window.print() that takes Start (X,Y) and End (X,Y) coordinates .Then in the dialog I can select pdf995 option to print as pdf.

For e.g. (23,45) to (93,100) pixels should print the area within that range. Instead of pixels, percentage should be good as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.  [How to get the X,Y coordinates of a point in a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668031/how-to-get-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-point-in-a-pdf)

On that question you should have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.awt.Robot ; java.awt.Image to take the ScreenShot and write a Image File (bmp or jpeg, or what you like); next, you can use Jasper Report to create a PDF and view the file report. Jasper its a powerfull library to create reports, website [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)

You can find some details to how take screen shots [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490454/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-java). Its also possible to take screen shots with cordinates. You can see some examples [here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/capture-screen-in-java-with-example.html#.VKrioNLF91Y)